# Como contar entradas em uma coluna mysql com apenas 1 select

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-html

Digamos que eu tenho uma coluna em uma tabela do meu banco MySql que se chama "alfabeto"

As entradas que tem na coluna seriam +/- assim:

[Ideia da tabela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xoxxg.png)

Eu preciso contar quantos A's, B's e C's tem nessa coluna. Sei que posso usar o "count" pra contar `SELECT count(*) FROM tabela`, mas ai ele me traria uma contagem de todas as entradas.

Agora a questão: Tem como fazer algo pra ele me trazer a quantidade de cada entrada (quantidade de A's, B's e C's) na coluna toda? Sem ficar fazendo um select/where pra cada letra? tipo isso: `$alfabeto = {A => 3, B => 2, C => 4}`

Answer (score 1):

creio que o jeito mais simples de obter quantos items tem de cada um seria fazer um GROUP BY algo tipo:

```
SELECT coluna_do_dado, count(*) FROM tabela GROUP BY coluna_do_dado
```

isso vai resultar em uma linha para cada entrada e o count dela